# Displaying content in the right div when the web page is loaded

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm clicking on list item links in my 'left' div and then displaying an html page in my 'right' div on my web page.  I'd like one of the html pages to be loaded when the web page is first loaded (i.e. as a default).  How can I do this?

Also, how can I get the background color to extend to the bottom of the 'right' div?  I've been creating divs with auto specifications and if my 'left' div is longer than the content in my 'right' div, I'll have a white bar at the bottom.

jQuery CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="initialLoad">
    $("#contactDetailsPane").load('listOfServices.htm');
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" id="jQueryCode">

    $(document).ready(
        function(){
            $('a.names').click(
                function(){
                    var thisId = $(this).attr('id');
                    $('#contactDetailsPane').fadeOut(400,
                    function(){
                        //$(this).load('tempPage.html #'+thisId+'Details');
                        $(this).load(thisId + '.htm');
                        var thisWidth = $(this).parents('dd').width();
                    }).fadeIn(600);

                    return false;
                }
            );
            $('.close').live('click',function(){
                $(this).parents('div').fadeOut();
            });
        }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: are you loading content to the right with ajax or frames ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest ajax request I can think about .. 
include jquery for this.

```
$(function(){
    $.get('htmldoc.html', function(data) {
       $('#resultdiv').html(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: this worked!  I'm accepting your answer.  I haven't been able to integrate this with my 3 column css layout, but the functionality is working now (i.e., loading an html page on initialization and loading html pages after clicking on the links).  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#idOfYourLink").click()
})
```

Comment: I'm already utilizing the 'click' functionality.  I want one of the list items loaded initially.

Comment: @jmac, this answer shows you how to actually trigger a click on one of your elements, so that it will load its content to the right..

Comment: @gaby, I'm already triggering the click of one of my elements.  I just wanted one of the elements loaded during the initialization of the web page and before the user explicitly clicks the link.  Zack listed a line of code that I was trying, but for some reason I can't get it to work for me.

Comment: @jmac, do you have a live page so we can work on something *tangible* so to say ..

Comment: @gaby, I'll edit my question and add my jquery code now.  I don't have a live page right now b/c this is replacing a site that's in production.

Answer (score 1):

initial load : before document.ready section: $("#rightDiv").load('path/to/html/file.html');

background color etc is css related : google is your friend!

Comment: I thought that it would be this simple, but it's not working.  I've included it within the 'script' and before my 'click' functionality.  I've also tried placing it in its own 'script' tag, but the page isn't loaded initially.  When I click on a link, each page is faded out and then faded into the 'right' div correctly.

Comment: I've posted the jQuery that you suggested and my script that is working by clicking on the link.

Answer (score 0):

When you say that you have an "HTML page" in your right `div`, do you mean that you have a whole new page loaded into an `iframe`?  Or is it just a plain ol' `div`?

To answer your second question, you can implement the layout described [here](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/).

Pay special attention to Step 6.

Comment: I have an html page loaded into a div (i.e., the right div is displaying the content of each html page after clicking a link in the left div).

Answer (score 0):

about the background color issue: look into creating a wrapper div around both of them and set the background color you want in that div's css properties. then set the backgrounds of the left and right div to be transparent.

ex in your html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
     <div id="left"></div>
     <div id="right></div>
</div>
```

and in your css:

```
#wrapper{
   background-color:#ff0000;
}

#left, #right{
background:transparent;
}
```

Comment: I had a colmask, colmid, and colleft wrapping three columns (i.e., col1, col2, and col3 on my main presentation).  This looks great, but I can't get the jquery code to post from the link in col1 to col2.  I'm trying to add just a 'wrapper' and all of my spacing is off then.

Comment: mmm it looks like you want to do something with the jquery ajax api here specifically the .load() method

example:

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#clickme').click(function(){
var link = $(this).attr('href');
$("#content").load(''+link + ' #content');
return false;
});
</script>

this will allow you to load in a page or part of a page into a div from a link on your page

http://api.jquery.com/load/